# how to post form with two parameter with hubot

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I want to post form like following curl with hubot.

```
curl -s -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H “X-AAA: aaa” -H “X-BBB: bbb” -X POST -d @${ACCOUNT_FILE} https://xxx/login


${ACCOUNT_FILE} is written.
login_id=loginid&password=password
```

I wrote following script but, It does not works.

auth.coffee

```
request = require 'request'
cheerio = require 'cheerio'
require('request').debug = true

module.exports = (robot) ->
  loginUrl = ‘https://xxx/login’
  headers = {
            ‘X-AAA’: ‘aaa’
            ‘X-BBB’: ‘bbb’
            }

  getAuth = (msg, loginid, password) ->
    options =
      url: loginUrl
      method: "POST"
      timeout: 2000
      headers: headers
      form: {
             'login_id': loginid
             'password': password
            }
    request options, (err, res, body) ->
      $ = cheerio.load body
      console.log($)
      msg.send "body is"
      msg.send $

  robot.hear /getauth/i, (msg) ->
    getAuth msg, 'loginid', 'password'
```

how to modify this script?

Comment: please state your expectations as detailed as possible. "does not work" does not help

Comment: Curl case server return status_code: 200 ok and body:json like "{"err_code":0,"result":{"access_token":"XXXXXX}}", but hubot case returns bad request ( I cannot see what happens in server side) , so I wonder my request in hubot was wrong some where.